# Redirect visitors first time visiting site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

So I need to redirect the visitors the first time they enter my site, regardless the entrypoint to the site.

I have implemented a global filter to search for a cookie and if that cookie doesn't exist, I create the cookie and redirect to the desired page.

It seems to be an expensive way to do this as every action will first check for the cookie. Is there a better way to achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: Performing something on every action isn't necessarily expensive. What is the actual overhead you've observed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for the presence of a cookie won't be an expensive operation to run on every action. That's the correct way to implement this feature and it won't hurt the performance of your site.

As an alternative method, if the client browsers support HTML5 local storage you could use javascript to store some value in local storage if the user has already visited your site. Then, once again, using javascript, on every page you could check for the presence of this value in local storage and if not present redirect the user to the landing page.